# Angular 6 clicked radio button doesn't update ngModel

Tags: angular, data-binding, ngfor, angular2-ngmodel

I have a radio group:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
  *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <input
    type="radio"
    [value]="category.id"
    [(ngModel)]="categoryModel.name">
     {{category.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],

})

export class Test {

  categories: {};
  categoryModel = {name: ''};

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {
    this.categories = [{
      id: 1, name: 'test1',
    },
    {
      id: 2, name:  'test2'
    },
    {
      id: 3, name:  'test3',
    },
  ]
}
```

When I click my radio, my model doesn't update, 
      {{categoryModel.name}} 
is still empty, what is wrong with it, how can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

**// Working code you can directly copy and paste the code and customize as per your requirement**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  categoryList: {};
  selectedCategory = { name: "" };

  constructor() {
    this.categoryList = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Option1' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Option2' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Option3' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Option4' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Option5' },
    ]
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>  Seleted Option:  {{selectedCategory.id}}- 
  {{selectedCategory.name }}</h1>
  <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
  *ngFor="let cat of categoryList">
    <input
    type="radio"
    [value]="cat"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory">
     {{cat.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks :)
Although i also had to add the name attribute to the radio buttons, so that the browser knows they belong to the same button group

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to the value of the radiobutton which is equal to the id of the category.

You can use the change event to get the name of the currently selected category like:

```
change(category_id){
 this.categoryModel.name = this.categories.find(c => c.id == category_id).name
}
```

An example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qeejnn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding `categoryModel.name`, you can bind `categoryModel`. To make it work, set the option values to `category` and make sure that the radio buttons have the same `name`.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <div *ngFor="let category of categories" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="category"
      [value]="category"
      [(ngModel)]="categoryModel">
      {{category.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ni8hcb) for a demo.